# Indicating level of Proficiency in Likes

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I love the new Careers 2.0 CV and the ability to host it online as well as producing a PDF (so recruiters have a way to file it).

One suggestion I have is the following: while I 'Like' a bunch of programming languages (say Python and Javascript in addition to C#) I am not as proficient in them (because I haven't actively used it in a while). I'd like a way to **self-rate my proficiency** so I can indicate to the recruiter (and interviewer) my knowledge in it.

Comment: Definitely +1. While I may get top 10% in a bunch of technologies, I would say that my abilities are *truly* expert level in a subset of those.

Answer (score 9):

Yep, this is something we've been thinking about.  A couple of ideas we've been kicking around:

### Rate your Technologies

For each technology you list, rate yourself in it, e.g.:

```
Like:  [c# *****] [asp.net ****] [java **] [python **]
```

(with better grahical treatment...)

### Multiple, Customizable Technology Lists

Create any number of lists and label them whatever you want, e.g.:

```
Expert:   [c#] [asp.net] [javascript]  
Familiar: [java] [jquery] [asp.net-mvc]    
Like:     [python] [ruby]   
Dislike:  [cobol] [tdd]
```

### Expandable Technology Details

Allow drilling down on a technology,
e.g.:

```
[c#]      5+ years of experience, top 10% on Stack Overflow, 2 open source projects, Microsoft MVP 2006 - Current  
[asp.net] 5+ years of experience, 2 open source projects
[jquery]  3+ years of experience, top 20% on Stack Overflow  
[sql]     3+ years of experience, top 20% on Stack Overflow
```

Thoughts / ideas? None of these are completely a home run, which is why we haven't implemented them yet...

Comment: Number 3 is probably the most meaningful for a hiring manager - I'd vote for that

Comment: I think #2 or #3 would be good, I think. #1 makes it too easy to confuse the skill rating with a measure of how much I like the technology, since the field is called "Like:".

Comment: @Anna good point, hadn't thought of that